# How to Toggle Active Class On each of Bootstrap btn-grruop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bunch of buttons inside a `btn-group` div which I have to set them all in active format ans ONLY toggle the class when the user clicks on the button.
Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/52VtD/3391/) which you can see After Removing active Class from the buttons they still keeps a light grey background! can you please ler me know what is this? and How can I get rid of that?
[image]

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">6</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").children().click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

And can you please let me know how I can get rid of the darker grey at the Top of the active class?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please let me know why did you vote my question down?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to remove the grey color in active buttons, just override it as follows:

```
.active{
  background-color:white !important;
}
```

*note:*

> And can you please let me know how I can get rid of the darker grey at the Top of the active class?

well, if you are reffering to the highlighted button in the second image, it doesn't have active class, it's a non-active class.
by setting all buttons as active initially,on first click it simply becomes inactive.
You might want to think about what you are doing.

**Update**
if you want to change the grey color you can do so by adding another class and toggling it as follows:

```
.select{
   background-color:white !important;
}
$("div").children().click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("select");
});
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EFQHN/)

Comment: Thanks Tiiwin, but this is not what I am looking for! I mean , my issue is having the grey background on the btns even after toggling the active class

Comment: you can see this easily on the provided demo

Comment: @user1760110 check the updated ans and fiddle. you might want to accept the ans if it helped you..